# difference between Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d') and Carbon::now(7)->format('Y-m-d')

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

i'm new in laravel

What is Difference between `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');` , `Carbon::now(7)->format('Y-m-d');` And

```
Carbon::now()->subDay(7)->format('Y-m-d');
```

Thank You

Comment: dd each value and see the difference

Comment: `now()` parameter is a timezone. Avoid to use an `integer` as a timezone, it's unclear, prefer `"UTC+07:00"` or even better: a named non-ambigous timezone: `"Atlantica/Azores"` (remember that some timezones have DST, that's why GMT+XY is not reliable for mutable dates in given areas) work in UTC back-end side, format in city timezone to output dates to some user.

Answer (score 3):

[image: With Format]

as we can see, there is almost no difference between the three if we use the "dd" function, except of course on `subDay` which stands for "subtract day" (I think).

but if we remove the format function in all three and use the default format of the "now" function

[image: Without Format]

We can see that

1. in the "now" function, carbon will return the current timestamps, this second, based on the timezone we set (in my case GMT + 7)
2. Because the parameter of the "now" function should be a string of timezone, so if we fill it with a number then carbon will return the default value, GMT -1.
3. As I explained above, Sunday will reduce the number of days the parameters entered, exactly at the current hour, minute, and second.

sorry for english, have a nice day